# Regular Expression to validate the Country code of mobile number in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression that will  test the input

1. Should start with only one + symbol or optional ( + should not come in between )
2. should not contain alphabets and any other special character
3. Should not contain consecutive + symbols

eg

- +91 (valid)
- 91 (valid)
- ++91 (invalid)
- +9+1 (invalid)
- 91+ (invalid)
- +91&*& (invalid)

Need your inputs on this . Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with plus (or not), at least 1 digit, all numerics.

```
^\+?\d+$
```

Comment: in this expression i can any add  number  of ++++ . ++91 , +91+2 is failing

Comment: Ok found, if you want to avoid +91&2 try to use ^\+?\d+$ to match exact string. ($ at end)

Comment: What if I only want to start with + and must have 1 number unconditional